is there any way to use coding inside geometry nodes like houdini's vex
I have a few ideas that are impossible with the current geometry nodes or would be better if I could use code directly like Houdini vex like a proper for each loop and so on. you know!

No. It is not possible. GN is designed for 0-coding for maximum computation speed and better UX. If you want coding - you can use Python and BPY for that.

I think Animation Nodes provide that. "I have a few ideas that are impossible with the current geometry nodes " - geonodes are turing-complete, so as long as you know how to input data to the system, and are fine with the ways the data can be output, you will be able to reproduce any algorithm - though some may be much slower than in competing languages. Also of course you can't use external libraries other than the limited ecosystem of geometry nodes custom groups.
